# Delta Lake: Partition by version (Azure Databricks)

Tags: azure, databricks, delta-lake

One of my delta tables is being used by an external service. However, the main requirement here is a good performance, and the tool performs really poorly reading delta format. Hence, what we currently do, is to use the Vacuum command in order to keep only the latest version of data in the delta table. The tool ignores delta log, so otherwise it would read all existing versions of the table at once. Then, it reads the parquet from a given directory.

I would like to go away from using Vacuum here, due to the issues with concurrency, and high costs it incurs on a table with big number of partitions. Say my delta table is currently partitioned on columns A, and B. Is there a way to force delta to write parquet files corresponding to different versions of the table into separate directories?

So that I can have a path where I know I only have the files that belong to the latest version of my delta table?
I.e

```
delta_table/A/B/version_1/

-> new version created -> 

delta_table/A/B/
              
version_1/
             
version_2/
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [delta-rs](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs).

You can install it with `pip install deltalake`.

Here's how to get all the latest files in the Delta table:

```py
dt = DeltaTable("resources/delta/1")
filenames = ["resources/delta/1/" + f for f in dt.files()]
```

delta-rs doesn't have a Spark dependency, so it's portable and lightweight.